# Should I Use a Self-Join

Tags: sql

If I have a table...

```
  ID     Name   Manager 
  0      Joe    Sue  
  1      Jake   Tom
  0      Joe    Tom
  2      Larry  Red
  2      Larry  Paul
  1      Jake   Paul
```

I want the output to be....

```
 ID   Name   Manager1    Manager2
 0    Joe    Sue         Tom
 1    Jake   Tom         Paul
 2    Larry  Red         Paul
```

Thanks...

Comment: Blech. And that's all I have to say about that.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use a self-join.

Comment: Ouch, a table with so much redundancy and without a proper primary key / index... Niiiiiice!

Comment: @Chouchenos we all have to start somewhere and learn how make good databases. =p

Comment: @Emerion Yeah, I know. I didn't mean to offense the user. Just trying to point out that, answering his question won't resolve his real mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, if your table was called 'Managers':

```
SELECT Mgr1.ID,Mgr1.Name,Mgr1.Manager,Mgr2.Manager
FROM Managers AS Mgr1
LEFT JOIN Managers AS Mgr2
ON Mgr1.ID=Mgr2.ID
```

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood your request properly, yes, something like would produce the results you are looking for.

```
SELECT
t1.Name Name,
t1.Manager Manager1,
t2.Manager Manager2
FROM
Table t1
inner join Table t2 on t1.Manager = t2.Name
```

Of course a foreign key back to the index column would be preferential to strong comparisons for performance.

Comment: Did you test this? I believe this query will not return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

If your keeping the tables a join would be best.

If you hate joins, you could combine the max and min managers, and even then it would work if there is always 2 managers and they can't have the same name.

The below should work if I remember how to join up 2 queries correctly. but i would advise to see if it is possible to rework your table, have a separate table linking people to each other in a manager employee relation.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    F.ID, F.Name, S.Manager, F.Manager
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ID, Name, MIN(manager) manager 
     FROM Managers 
     GROUP BY ID, Name) F,
    (SELECT
         ID, Name, MAX(manager) manager 
     FROM Managers 
     GROUP BY ID, Name) S
WHERE 
    F.ID = S.ID
    AND S.Manager <> F.Manager
    AND F.ID < S.ID
```